# Dokku DigitalOceans droplet: remote rejected error... how to solve it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean, dokku

I recently heard about Dokku, and wanted to deploy a dockerized Rails application using the DigitalOceans droplet. I followed [these](http://www.rubyfleebie.com/2018/12/14/how-to-use-dokku-on-digitalocean-and-deploy-rails-applications-like-a-pro/) guidelines, and everything seemed working fine... till I tried to push on Dokku :'( I get always the same "remote rejected error", but with not explicits informations that could help me to solve my problem... So if anyone could help, it would be really great!

Here are my steps:

1. Created the droplet, with the 5$ plan. On setup I left the fields as they were (hostname, ...).
2. Added a swap file (as recommended in the tutorial)
3. Created the dokku app, and linked it to the PG plugin I installed just before
4. Added the remote as `git remote add dokku dokku@my-droplet-ip:myapp`
5. Updated the DB url on my Rails configuration
6. Pushed my branch using `git push dokku <branchname>`: for branchname other than master, you have to configure Dokku... ;)

**Dokku push logs:** https://gist.github.com/soykje/1ddeb5f04fd85e8bd2d2b1f46e63da1e

**Dokku app report:** https://gist.github.com/soykje/f5192775742848f96437705c6608080f

Thx in advance

Comment: I was able to go further, after discovering that Dokku has a "default branch" (master)... In order to make this work, I had to change this setting. Now it simply fails... I have a lot of logs, but no explanation :( https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/3503

Comment: In your logs it says `remote: + dokku_log_fail 'App container failed to start!!` - sure the app / container is working ok?

Comment: No, but I can't figure out why it could not work... I guess it is due to my Dockerfile, as the docker-compose.yml is not used with Dokku ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to include a file named `Procfile` in the root of the project with the contents of

```
release: bundle exec rails db:migrate
web: bundle exec rails s
```

https://dokku.com/docs/deployment/builders/dockerfiles/#procfiles-and-multiple-processes